# Close automatic opened css accordion menu

Tags: css

I'm using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NmVhG/3/) accordion for a menu but it has a panel which is open automatically, I'm wondering how I can have it so no panels are open until it is clicked. This is a pure css menu but I can't figure out why it's open automatically.

```
    body {background: #e0e3ec url(http://netcribe.com/example/bgnoise_lg.jpg) repeat top left;}

    .ac-container{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
    }

    .ac-container label{
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #777;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 19px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%, #eaeaea 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 1%,#eaeaea 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 );
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9) inset, 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
}

    .ac-container label:hover{
        background: #fff;
    }

    .ac-container input:checked + label,
    .ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
    background: #c6e1ec;
    color: #3d7489;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 
        0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3), 
        0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 13px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(http://netcribe.com/example/arrow_down.png) no-repeat center center;  
}

.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after {
    background-image: url(http://netcribe.com/example/arrow_up.png);
}

.ac-container input{
    display: none;
}

.ac-container article{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article {
     -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
    height: 100px;
}

.ac-container article p{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" checked />`

to `<input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />`

Remove the `checked`.  It seems the accordion relies on these checkboxes being checked.  Remove the `checked` and it won't open.

Comment: Thankyou, knew it would be simple but I assumed it was to do with the CSS.